# Express routing: How to take user to an optional validation flow and back?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, routes, query-string

I have a Node Express web app, on which I need to implement this flow:

> 1. **`/product/:productId/buy`**: User submits a form with Name, Address and phone number that I submit to my API layer
> 2. API responds with `201` for `All good`, and `202` for `Order submitted, but we need to verify your mobile number first`
> 3. **`/product/:productId/confirm`**: If `201`, show user the confirmation screen
> 4. **`/verify/phone`**: If `202`, take user to a phone verification screen that says: `Verify your phone number: <insert phone number
>      entered at step#1> with the OTP sent to your phone`
> 5. **`/product/:productId/confirm`**: User enters OTP. Hit API, verify and take them to the confirmation screen. Else reload
>      **`/verify/phone`**

I have setup the following routes:

```
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/product/: productId/buy',
        action: ['productController', 'getBuyForm']
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/product/: productId/buy',
        action: ['productController', 'postBuyForm']
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/verify/phone',
        action: ['verificationController', 'getVerificationForm']
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/verify/phone',
        action: ['verificationController', 'postVerificationForm']
    }
```

When I `POST` the `postBuyForm`, I submit `phone`, `address` and `name` in the request body.

The server responds with an empty body and a status code.

Now, if the status code is `202` I need to navigate to the `verify/phone` page, but I also need to somehow carry forward the `phone` value that I submitted with the `postBuyForm` because I need to display it on the page.

One option to do this, is to use:

**`res.redirect('verify/phone/'+phone)`**

But my business doesn't want the phone number to be part of the query string, as this will allow misuse.

Another option is to use sessions like mentioned below by @circusbred:

```
app.post('/product/: productId/buy', (req, res) => {
  req.session.phone = phone;
});

app.get('/verify/phone', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.phone);
});
```

But we're trying to not use session as by design we only use session for authenticated users and this functionality has to work for non-authenticated users as well.

My question is this:

**Is there a way to navigate or redirect to the verification page, while passing the `phone` value along without having to include it in the query string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only viable option is to utilize [sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) of some sort.

```
app.post('/product/: productId/buy', (req, res) => {
  req.session.phone = phone;
});

app.get('/verify/phone', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.phone);
});
```

Comment: I thought of that too. In fact I'll add that in the description as well. We're trying to not utilize session as by design we only use session for authenticated users and this functionality has to work for non-authenticated users as well. Any other way?